# Java sync class and this by two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads, t1 and t2 of the same class; t1 synchronizes on the class itself, while t2 synchronizes on `this` (the instance).
Assuming t1 entered the synchronization block, can t2 enter while t1 is still in its synchronization block?

Edit:
Example:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
private int id;
public MyThread(int i){id=I;}
public void run(){
    if(id==1)//t1 will lock the clas
        synchronize(MyThread.class){
            …
        }
    else if(id==2) //t2 will lock the instance
        synchronize(this){
            …
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the code. Reduce it to a simple test case if possible.  And also, try running it to see what happens before asking.  A developer's most important skill is the ability to experiment to figure out how code behaves.

Comment: I think the answer is Yes.  But I could have misunderstood the question, and the real answer could be No.

Comment: @JimGarrison I added an example code

Comment: And the reason I asked it its because it was a question in a test, I ran it and got one results, my friends ran it and got contradicting results, so we had a debate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example,

- All MyThread instances created with `id` of `1` will synchronize on the `MyThread` class object.  This means that no two `MyThread` instances can be "in" the first `synchonized` block at the same time.
- All `MyThread` instances created with `id` of `2` will synchronize on `this`.  Now `this` is the thread object itself<sup>1</sup>.  Since every thread has a different `MyThread`, that means that there will effectively be no locking.
- The run method for an instance with `id` value `1` will not block an instance with `id` value `2`, or vice versa.  They are using different locks.

---

<sup>1 - In theory, if one thread could access another thread's `MyThread` object, it could explicitly call the `run()` method on that object.  After all, the method is `public`. In that case, the `this` would not be the current thread ... and therefore you would potentially have locking.  However, this is not the kind of thing that a sane programmer would do.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the second thread can enter its synchronized block while the first thread is still in its synchronized block.  That's because the two threads are synchronizing on different things - the first thread on a class, the second thread on an instance of that class.